# Conditions in a match arm without destructuring

Tags: rust

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn cmp(a: i32, b: i32) -> Ordering {
    match {
        _ if a < b => Ordering::Less,
        _ if a > b => Ordering::Greater,
        _ => Ordering::Equal,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = 10;

    println!("{}", match cmp(x, y) {
        Ordering::Less => "less",
        Ordering::Greater => "greater",
        Ordering::Equal => "equal",
    });
}
```

How to use `match` with conditions, without destructuring (because there's nothing to destructure), in the function `cmp` above?

The code has been adapted from the well-known example in the book which uses only if/else, however, it does not work:

```
src/main.rs:5:9: 5:10 error: unexpected token: `_`
src/main.rs:5         _ if a < b => Ordering::Less,
                      ^
Could not compile `match_ordering`.
```

I am using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (3ef8ff1f8 2015-02-12 00:38:24 +0000)`.

This would work:

```
fn cmp(a: i32, b: i32) -> Ordering {
    match (a, b) {
        (a,b) if a < b => Ordering::Less,
        (a,b) if a > b => Ordering::Greater,
        _ => Ordering::Equal,
    }
}
```

but it would use destructuring. Is there any other way, or is this just the most idiomatic, clean way of writing it?

Comment: For this specific case, I hope you know that `<i32 as Ord>::cmp` is equivalent to your `cmp` function? (You could also thus write `x.cmp(y)`.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan yes, I do. The sole purpose is learning and understanding rust idioms.

Comment: what's wrong with `if a < b { Ordedering::Less } else if a > b { Ordering::Greater } else { Ordering::Equal }`? Conditions are also expressions.

Comment: @ker Nothing is wrong with it, I just know how to program that way, and I am seeking a deeper knowledge of what might be more idiomatic in rust. Is it hard to understand what I'm saying, or is it hard to accept it?

Comment: I'm assuming it's more idiomatic to use conditions as an expression than a match on nothing. But i might be wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to match on something, i.e. `match { ... }` isn't valid because there needs to be something between the `match` and the `{`. Since you don't care about the value itself, matching on unit, `()`, should be fine: `match () { ... }`, e.g.:

```
match () {
    _ if a < b => Ordering::Less,
    _ if a > b => Ordering::Greater,
    _ => Ordering::Equal
}
```

(To be strict: `match { _ => ... }` is actually trying to parse the `{ ... }` as the match head (i.e. the expression being matched on), and `_` isn't valid at the start of an expression, hence the error.)

On idiomacity: I personally think expressing a series of conditions with short results (like this) is fine with `match` and a series of `_ if ...`s as you have done.

Comment: So what would the syntax look like?

Comment: @Flavius: I give the syntax in my answer: `match () {`. :)